# _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Topic>'

Tags: json, flutter

So I am new to flutter development and this is the first thing I stumbled over.

I want to **read a json file** and "convert" it to **dart classes**.

This is my JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Deutsch",
        "topics": [
            {
                "name": "Rechtschreibung",
                "contents": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Grammatik",
                "contents": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Textanalyse",
                "contents": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Mathematik",
        "topics": [
            {
                "name": "Vektorrechnung",
                "contents": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Geometrie",
                "contents": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Polynomdivision",
                "contents": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my subject model:

```
import './topic.dart';

class Subject {
  String _name;
  List<Topic> _topics;

  Subject(this._name, this._topics);

  factory Subject.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json != null) {
      return Subject(json['name'], json['topics']);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  get name => this._name;
  get topics => this._topics;
}
```

and this the topic model:

```
import './content.dart';

class Topic {
  String _name;
  List<Content> _contents;

  Topic(this._name, this._contents);

  factory Topic.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json != null) {
      return Topic(json['name'], json['contents']);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  get name => this._name;
  get contents => this._contents;
}
```

The error message raises in the subject model at **json['topics']**:

`_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Topic>')`

I would be really grateful if someone has a clue how I can get around this!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that you will always have `Topic` in `json['topics']`

then you can cast it before adding it to subject:

```
return Subject(json['name'], json['topics'] as Topic);
```

Comment: Now it tells me: `_CastError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Topic>' in type cast)`

Comment: this solved it for me: `return Subject(json['name'], json['topics'].cast<Topic>());`

Comment: @TimoMüller thats why I mention "If you are sure..." You may want to look: https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/736